# Formatting data written to C++ stream using write method

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to write the contents of a pointer to a stream in hex. I've tried setting the stream to use the hex format flag, but it doesn't seem to have an effect when using the write method.  Below is my current code:

```
char* pointerToData;
size_t dataLength;
....
out.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);
out.setf(std::ios::showbase);
out.write(pointerToData, dataLength);
os.unsetf(std::ios::showbase);
```

Comment: You will have to use `std::ostringstream` to write formatted text to a string or buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hex` flag affects how integer values are formatted.  When you call `write` with a buffer it's not formatting anything.  You need something roughly like this:

```
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < dataLength; ++ii) {
    out << int(pointerToData[ii]);
}
```